# How to test arrow function calling in react component with jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

im newbie in jest/enzyme testing with react and im trying to test react Button Component by passing props and im getting this error **Cannot read property 'onIncrement' of undefined**.

```
describe("Name of the group", () => {
  const counter = 'pc';
  const onIncrement = jest.fn();
  const props = {
    onIncrement,
    counter
};
it("should be clicked ", () => {
  const button = shallow(<Button {...{props}}>Increment</Button>);
  button.find(".increment").simulate("click");
  expect(button).toHaveBeenCalledWith('pc');
  });
  });
```

---

```
   import React from "react";
   export const Button = ( props ) => {
     return (
       <button
        id="inc"
        className="increment"
        onClick={() => props.onIncrement(props.counter)}
       >
        Increment
       </button>
     );
    };
```

Comment: There is a mistake in tested component, `({ props })`. It's `(props)`. Also `jest.fn((e) => (onIncrement = e))` doesn't make sense, why would you reassign spy function, not to mention that it's a constant?

Comment: check now i reasssigned it now and passing object with values. and trying to get back  the id value if clicked.

const counter = {id:1, value:0};
  const onIncrement = jest.fn();
  const props = {
    onIncrement,
    counter
  };
  it("should be clicked ", () => {
    const button = shallow(<Button {...props}>Increment</Button>);
    button.find(".increment").simulate("click");
    expect(button).toHaveBeenCalledWith(counter.id===1);
  });

Comment: `<Button {...{props}}>` is an another mistake. It will pass props object with props key. It should be `<Button {...props}>` as it was before. The answer mentions it because `<Button {...{props}}>` is a way that could make `({ props })` work, but it shouldn't be like that any way.

Comment: yeah thanks man i got the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change this:

```
export const Button = ({ props }) => {} // component has a property called props
```

to this:

```
export const Button = (props) => {}
```

Otherwise:

```
// it is not recommended
const button = shallow(<Button {...{props}}>Increment</Button>);
```

**Edit:**

This should works:

```
export const Button = (props) => {
  return (
    <button
     id="inc"
     className="increment"
     onClick={() => props.onIncrement(props.counter)}
    >
     Increment
    </button>
  );
 };
describe("Name of the group", () => {
  const counter = "pc";
  const props = {
    onIncrement: jest.fn(),
    counter,
  };

  it("should ", () => {
    const button = shallow(<Button {...props}>Increment</Button>);
    button.find(".increment").simulate("click");
    expect(props.onIncrement).toHaveBeenCalledWith("pc");
  });
});
```

Comment: this is not working for me. not reading the onIncrement property now.

Comment: props.onIncrement is not a function. this is what im getting

Comment: In your code onIncrement is already a spy, it doesn't need spyOn.

Comment: Yes, you are right, I will update my answer, thanks @EstusFlask